# How to enable SSL for custom port in docker (without redirection)

Tags: docker, ssl

I'm having trouble setting up SSL with custom port in docker (without redirection).

This is my files:

*`docker-compose.yml`*

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  apache-php:
    container_name: apache-php
    image: php:7.4.8-apache
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./web:/var/www/html
      - ./ssl:/etc/apache2/ssl
      - ./sites-enabled:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./ports.conf:/etc/apache2/ports.conf
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 2805:2805
```

*`sites-enabled/example.com.conf`*

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

Listen 2805
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:2805>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/manage
    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/manage-error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/manage-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com

    SSLEngine On

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.key

    SSLProxyEngine On

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://example.com:2805/
        ProxyPassReverse http://example.com:2805/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I generated certificate files using the command of [lynxman](https://serverfault.com/users/66198/lynxman) at https://serverfault.com/a/224127

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > ssl/example.com.key
chmod 400 ssl/example.com.key
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 365 -key ssl/example.com.key -out ssl/example.com.crt
```

Then I run `docker-compose up` command, everything works fine

I can access to http://example.com:2805 but can't access to domain with SSL https://example.com:2805

And I have received the message of the browser:

> This site can't provide a secure connection
>
> example.com sent an invalid response.
>
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Any help is much appreciated as I am really struggling here.

Comment: Why do you have 3 ports. Why are you trying to change the default 443 port on the container? Have you generated the certificates and placed them in the proper directories that you are mounting to the container? If I write a Dockerfile that generates self-signed certificates and listens on :80 and :443(without redirection), just ready to be used, will it satisfy your question?

Comment: @NeoAnderson Thank you for your reply.
I have the certificate files, please see the update of my question above.
And currently I am running docker on cloud VPS, I want using port 80 for user and port 2805 for admin but it also needs to support SSL for both normal and custom ports (such as port 2805).
I don't know how to configure docker to working correctly.
Any of your help is worth it to me.

Comment: why aren‘t you connecting to the configured https port 443? Both  other unsecured ones shouldnt be exposed  outside the container